# Cuando hago ruby htmlImg.rb https://ejemplo.com/index.html obtengo

Tags: ruby

Cuando ejecuto mi *script* con:

```
$ ruby htmlImg.rb https://ejemplo.com/index.html
```

obtengo este error:

```
 /usr/share/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:479:in `get_response': undefined method `hostname' for "https://twitter.com/Yojiexo":String (NoMethodError)
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:456:in `get'
        from htmlImg.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Este el código:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'net/http'

pagina = Net::HTTP.get(ARGV[0],ARGV[1])
enlace = Nokogiri::HTML(pagina).xpath('//pag[@href]').map {|link| link['href']}
imagen = Nokogiri::HTML(pagina).xpath('//img[@src]').map {|link| link ['src']}
puts "Los enlaces son: " + enlace
puts "Las direcciones de imagenes son: " + imagen
```

Answer (score 0):

Dado que estás pasando la URI completa (i.e. https://ejemplo.com/index.html) necesitas convertirla en objeto `URI`<sup>1</sup> para que el método `get` la reconozca; por ejemplo:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'net/http'

pagina = Net::HTTP.get(URI(ARGV[0]))
enlace = Nokogiri::HTML(pagina).xpath('//a[@href]').map { |link| link['href'] }
imagen = Nokogiri::HTML(pagina).xpath('//img[@src]').map { |link| link ['src'] }

puts "Los enlaces son: #{enlace}" 
puts "Las direcciones de imagenes son: #{imagen}"
```

Si te das cuenta, únicamente estás pasando un argumento a tu script *htmlImg.rb*, por lo que `ARGV` sólo tendrá *1 valor* el cual estará en la posición `0` (i.e. `ARGV[0]`).

Adicionalmente, notarás algunas correcciones:

- Cambié `pag[@href]` por `a[@href]` para poder encontrar los enlaces.
- Dado que `enlace` e `imagen` son arreglos, hay que convertirlos a *string*, utilizando `#{..}` automáticamente llama al método `to_s`.

<sup><sup>1</sup> *Visita [este enlace](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-GET) para más información sobre la clase `Net::HTTP` y su método `get`.*</sup>